# Using commands (/) in inline mode for a Telegram bot

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot

I use python-telegram-bot wrapper.

For a command that is called upon using '/' I have the following method:

```py
def advice(update, context):
    with open ("advice.txt", "rt") as file_advice:
        line=file_advice.readlines()
        advice_message=random.choice(line)
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text=advice_message)

advice_handler = CommandHandler('advice', advice)
dispatcher.add_handler(advice_handler)
```

I want this method to be called in inline mode when '/advice' is typed and there should be no output in all other cases.

I'm familiar with examples from the wrapper developers, where they show the following code:

```py
def inline_caps(update, context):
    query = update.inline_query.query
    if not query:
        return
    results = list()
    results.append(
        InlineQueryResultArticle(
            id=query.upper(),
            title='Caps',
            input_message_content=InputTextMessageContent(query.upper())
        )
    )
    context.bot.answer_inline_query(update.inline_query.id, results)

inline_caps_handler = InlineQueryHandler(inline_caps)
dispatcher.add_handler(inline_caps_handler)
```

I tried to swap `query.upper()` with `advice(update, context)` but there are different errors about unknown type so feels like I don't know what I'm doing.

Comment: Attach errors which you are getting and which you don't understand. This is important part of the question you missed I think.

Answer (score 0):

It won't work like that because InputTextMessageContent() requieres a string at least and your function doesn't return a string. In that case I would rewrite the advice function so you can reuse it in your command handler and your inline handler.

```
import random
from uuid import uuid4

def getAdvice():
    with open ("advice.txt", "rt") as file_advice:
        line=file_advice.readlines()
        advice_message=random.choice(line)
    return advice_message

def advice(update, context):
    advice_message=getAdvice()
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text=advice_message)

def inlinequery(update, context):
    query = update.inline_query.query
    results = [
        InlineQueryResultArticle(
            id=uuid4(),
            title="/advice",
            input_message_content=InputTextMessageContent(
                getAdvice()))
        ]
    update.inline_query.answer(results)

advice_handler = CommandHandler('advice', advice)
dispatcher.add_handler(advice_handler)
inlinequery_handler = InlineQueryHandler(inlinequery)
dispatcher.add_handler(inlinequery_handler)
```